# Microtime inaccurate time measurement?

Tags: php

I just found out about microtime() in PHP. 
I tried to check how long it will take to execute basic image load. 
Here is code:

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);


    echo("<img src='http://example.com/public/images/new.png'/>");

    $time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start;
    echo($time_elapsed_secs);
?>
```

On average it returns: "8.8214874267578E-6" which I assume means 8.82 seconds?
Did I do something wrong? I am sure image loads faster than 8 seconds, I would definitely notice 8 seconds.

Here is image itself:
[image]

Comment: Did you see the `E-6` at the end? -> `X * 10 ^ -6` is the time it takes

Comment: If you want to measure how long it takes to load an image use Javascript (or even better just hit F12 and look at the timeline on the network tab of developer tools). You aren't measuring how long it took to load an image in the above code. You're measuring how long it took for PHP to write a 53 character string to its output buffer. The image is downloaded much later, and on the machine that is rendering that HTML, not on your server which is just outputting that HTML.

Comment: [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)

Comment: I see, that means echo was executed in 0.0000088214874268 seconds.

Comment: Yes it does.... note that is the time simply to execute the echo statement, not to return the page to your browser, nor for the browser to request/receive the image itself

Comment: @MarkBaker yes I understand now, I just used F12 method suggestion, it displays 168 ms which equals to 0.168 seconds, would that be right?

Comment: That's right: though a good dev tool will tell you what time it took to execute the dns lookup for the url, connection time, any ssl overhead, latency, time to download, etc

Comment: @MarkBaker what about mysqli_query command? I assume microtime script in question would measure it?

Comment: @arletiss - Correct. Both "echo" and "mysqli_query" are what's called blocking calls - meaning they block the execution of the rest of the script until they finish. Actually, almost all calls in PHP are blocking (there are a couple extremely useful exceptions in a very advanced type of PHP that involves setting up multiple CPU threads). Basically each line of PHP code stops the script until it's done. "echo <img/>" takes an instant because it's just writing some text out to the page. It doesn't need confirmation. mysqli_query blocks until it gets a result. So yes, in that case microtime works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The E-6 at the end of that string means you need to move the decimal six places to the left.

By the way, the echo statement executes almost instantly, writing that HTML to the output stream. That doesn't mean the image loaded that fast in some remote browser reading the HTML stream and trying to load the image.

Comment: Decimal place should be moved to the left.

Comment: Oh, is there any way to measure how fast image loads?

Comment: Yes hehheh, to the left. Thanks chris85. Sucks to be mildly dyslexic sometimes.

Comment: You can measure how quickly the image loads using a browser's developer tools

Comment: Yes. Or there are various ways you can use javascript to measure it, which is beyond the scope of the question; the point is, that measurement has to take place on the client side, in the browser. OP is confused between the nature of server-side and client-side code.